# Trying to persist another entity in preUpdate

Tags: symfony, events, listener

I'm trying to persist another entity in my preUpdate event listener, but it's not working...

Here is my code:

```
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity        = $args->getEntity();
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow           = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $session       = new Session();
    $newLog = new Log();
    $newLog->setDate(new DateTime());

    if(!empty($this->toBePersisted))
    {
       array_push($toBePersisted, $historique);
    }
    else
    {
       $toBePersisted[0] = $historique;
    }
}


    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $event)
{
    if(!empty($this->toBePersisted)) {

        $em = $event->getEntityManager();

        foreach ($this->toBePersisted as $element) {

            $em->persist($element);
        }

        $this->toBePersisted = [];
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

But my new log is not persisted...
Do you have any solution ?

Regards

Comment: Might sound dumb but update events occur only if the entity actually has changed, are you making changes to it when you run your tests ? Also, why don't you simply persist your log in the preUpdate() method instead of storing them in an array and persisting them later?

Comment: What error do you get? This SHOULD throw error at you, since $historique is not defined in your code.

Comment: Can you update the question with concrete use case? What is triggering entity doing? What is $historique meant to be?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong listeners to implement what you want to do. Quoting from Doctrine [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#postflush) for postFlush event:

> postFlush is called at the end of EntityManager#flush(). EntityManager#flush() can NOT be called safely inside its listeners.

The right way to implement what you want is inside the onFlush event which is the more powerful doctrine event but is NOT a lifecycle callback. So you have to proper set up your listener in your services.yaml:

```
App\EventListener\LogListener:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }
```

and then in onFlush event:

```
class LogListener {

public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args) {
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if (!$entity instanceof YourUpdatedEntity) {
            return;
        }

        $newLog = new Log();
        $newLog->setDate(new DateTime());
        $em->persist($newLog);
        $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(Log::class);
        $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $newLog);
    }
}

}
```

The computeChangeSet function call is needed because as stated in the documentation for onFlush event:

> If you create and persist a new entity in onFlush, then calling EntityManager#persist() is not enough. You have to execute an additional call to $unitOfWork->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity).